# Unable to fully teardown AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

On iOS after using AVAudioPlayer to play a sound I observe that a thread continues to run and consume around 3% CPU. It seems related to the HAL stuff (Hardware Abstraction Layer).
How to achieve a full cleanup and get my app idle ?
It is referenced in a local var and properly deallocated after the play is ended.
I've noticed that If I just instantiate the AVAudioPlayer but never call the play method, that thread is not created. And the app is idle.
Any ideas?

Notice: I deprecate this question since I've realised that this issue is only on Simulator. Found the explanation here http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2006/Jul/msg00022.html

Comment: is your instance of player local or global?

Comment: did you try `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:NULL]`? that helped me a lot when using using components from different AV frameworks...

Comment: Yes I call [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:NULL] after the track is played.

Answer (score 1):

How is the exact name of the object which is using 3% cpu?

Have you tried running the App in instruments?

[Instruments Usage Manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Especially check for leaks and where they are created.

Comment: Well the HALRunLoop is scheduled by some objective object, and when this object is released it should unschedule this Runloop.

Also, the link you posted claims that the Halrunloop is ina  mixed environment, so another App might be using it at the same time. So you might just not see it as long as you don't play something, or it might just be kept by some player in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and set your audio player object to nil.

```
NSError *error;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withFlags:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&error];
```